Looking for an `ignore` function which returns t
I want to create a new function which just calls a given function do-the-work but chanegs all calls to y-or-n-p which happen inside of  do-the-work to return always t.
At the moment I do it like this:
(defun no-confirm (prompt) t)

(defun my-changed-do-the-work ()
  (interactive)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'y-or-n-p) #'no-confirm))
    (do-the-work)))

but I was wondering whether there is a standard function which I could use instead of no-confirm -- kind of an ignore function which always returns t not nil.

Have you tried using ignorealways?
always is a natively compiled function defined in subr.el.gz.

Signature
(always &rest ARGUMENTS)

Documentation
Ignore ARGUMENTS, do nothing, and return t.

This function accepts any number of arguments in ARGUMENTS.
Also see ignore.

Note (from a comment by @phils):
The function above is only built inEmacs 28 and later.  If you use an earlier version then (lambda (&rest _) t) is such a function. Or you can (defun always (&rest _) t). Or you can install/depend upon the GNU ELPA compat package, which provides always.

Only since 28.1 (confirmed by NEWS), despite describe-function perplexingly suggesting that it's "probably" been there since 25.1 or earlier.

Ah, I see; it is NEWS-based, and NEWS.25 (and in indeed NEWS.26) make mention of 'always' too.  Those cases are potential values for various variables rather than a function, but help-fns--first-release doesn't know the difference (hence the "probably").

If you're not using Emacs 28.1 or later then (lambda (&rest _) t) is such a function.  Or you can (defun always (&rest _) t).  Or you can install/depend upon the GNU ELPA compat package, which provides always.

Excellent. Good to know. @phils Thanks for your details too. I have added them to the answer.
